# ruby on rails: .project file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For some reason, when I create my project, the .project file is missing. Which command creates this file?/Why is it missing from my project directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This file is created by your IDE.  Likely Aptana.  It is not required to run rails and usually ends up on my .gitignore file if I am working with others who use Aptana.

Comment: what is the correct way to import the project into aptana? I try to import -> existing folding as new project and I get .project is read only error.

Comment: I don't use it myself, but I would chmod the .project file to 755 and then import it.

Comment: what do you use if not aptana?

Comment: I use gvim.  I am not overly familiar with Aptana, sorry that I can't assist further.  Perhaps changing your topic to something more related many yield more results.

Answer (score 1):

Running `rails new foo` from the CLI doesn't create that file. As @Gazler said, it's created by your IDE. Most likely Aptana or Eclipse, as that IDE uses .project files.